# Connecting to hosted web3 provider from NodeJS backend

Tags: web3js, ropsten, infura, web3-providers

I'm using these instructions from [etherchain](https://etherchain.org/api/web3/). [Here's](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2080/error-invalid-json-rpc-response-undefined-from-node-web3-js-app) a similar question(**seems like duplicate, but it's not**). The solution provided there doesn't work for me, because I don't have a local ethereum client to connect to. I want to use one provided by **Etherchain**.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://rpc.ethapi.org:8545"));
web3.eth.getBlock("latest", (error, result) => {
  console.log('error:', error);
  console.log('results', result);
});
```

**Error:**

```
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
   at Object.InvalidResponse (/home/manid/Рабочий стол/Pogovorim/NODE_SERVER/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:35:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/home/manid/Рабочий стол/Pogovorim/NODE_SERVER/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:116:32)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/home/manid/Рабочий стол/Pogovorim/NODE_SERVER/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/home/manid/Рабочий стол/Pogovorim/NODE_SERVER/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpRequestError (/home/manid/Рабочий стол/Pogovorim/NODE_SERVER/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:544:12)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/manid/Рабочий стол/Pogovorim/NODE_SERVER/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:414:24)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:309:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1281:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your solution is probably in here. http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2080/error-invalid-json-rpc-response-undefined-from-node-web3-js-app

Comment: @tayvano, thank you! That solution doesn't work for me, because I'm connecting to a remote host and the solution provided there is for connection to geth node running on local machine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've replaced

```
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://rpc.ethapi.org:8545"));
```

with:

```
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/TOKEN"));
```

and everything works.

This `https://ropsten.infura.io/TOKEN` was given to me after registration on [infura.io](http://infura.io)

Comment: Seems like `rpc.ethapi.org` is down: http://isup.me/rpc.ethapi.org

Comment: I have tried what you suggested to connect to ropsten but i get an error Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: "" at Object.module.exports.InvalidResponse (/Blockchain/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:35:16) at HttpProvider.send (/Blockchain/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:91:22) at RequestManager.send (/Blockchain/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:58:32) at Eth.send [as sendTransaction] (/Blockchain/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:145:58) at SolidityFunction.sendTransaction (/Blockchain/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/function.js:148:26) at SolidityFunction.execute (/Blo

Comment: i think u mean https://ropsten.infura.io/[API_KEY]? to avoid the confusion to token smart contract....